# How to replace HTML content of <span> tag with value of input field without setting the value of input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a message saying Hey There. I would like to replace the 'There' text with the value being typed in the input box.

I tried using directive

HTML

```
<div id="updateName">
<!--form sec-->
<section class="animated container-fluid align-center sec-ptop">
<h3 class="salutation">Hey <span>{{inputName}}There</span>, happy to hear from you.</h3>
<div>
<form name="contactform" method="post" class="row form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group input--josh col-sm-6">
<div class="input-wrap">
<input autocomplete="off" v-init type="text" v-model="inputName" class="form-control input__field input input__field--josh" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Name" value="" required />
<label class="input__label input__label input__label--josh input__label--josh-color-1 input__label--josh input__label--josh-color-1"></label>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

vue

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#updateName',
    data: {
        inputName: 'There'
    },
    directives: {
        init: {
            bind(el){
                el.value = el.getAttribute('value');
                el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
            }
        }
    },
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="updateName">
<!--form sec-->
<section class="animated container-fluid align-center sec-ptop">
<h3 class="salutation">Hey <span>{{inputName}}There</span>, happy to hear from you.</h3>
<div>
<form name="contactform" method="post" class="row form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group input--josh col-sm-6">
<div class="input-wrap">
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" v-model="inputName" v-on:keyup.enter="replaceText(inputValue)" class="form-control input__field input input__field--josh" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Name" required />
<label class="input__label input__label input__label--josh input__label--josh-color-1 input__label--josh input__label--josh-color-1"></label>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

vue

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#updateName',
    data: {
        inputName: 'There'
    },
    methods: {
        replaceText: function(inValue) {
            this.inputName = this.inputName + inValue           
        }
    }
});
```

**On page load**

Hey There, happy to hear from you.

Name

[image: on page load]

**On run-time**

Hey John, happy to hear from you.

John

On Run Time
[image: on run time]

Comment: `v-model` is enough, remove `value`,`v-init` and `replaceText` from the input; in case it does not work, are there any console errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether we can populate the form data while a form submit.

If you want to submit the form data then you have to prevent ( event.preventdefault ) the form data and saved it into another variable.

But if you no need to submit the form means you can achieve it by using my below sample code

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  

    <div id='myApp'>
        <h3 class="myName">Hey <span v-if='inputName.length'>{{inputName}}</span> <span v-else>There</span>, happy to hear from you.</h3>
        <form method="post"> 
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" v-model="inputName" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Name" />
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myInstance = new Vue({
        el:'#myApp',
        data:{
            inputName : ''
        }

    })
</script>
```

You have to do the same for the rest of the place you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your method because you use the 'v-model', which says that if your input changes, your data will change too.

You can also remove your span tag if you don't need to change something on the name and remove the static 'There' in your span.

```
<h3 class="salutation">Hey <span>{{inputName}}</span>, happy to hear from you.</h3>
```

is the same as

```
<h3 class="salutation">Hey {{inputName}}, happy to hear from you.</h3>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fo21ykru/)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Your code should have some condition either v-if / v-show for show / hide the "THERE" string. Because if once the user type something means we no need to show the "THERE" string at the moment as per the question. Hope you understood.

Comment: Hi Takachi, the input still has the 'There' text in it which I did not want. Kanna's code helped.